# Addition of numbers obtained in foreach in C#

Tags: c#, .net, hard-drive

With the following code, I will receive the volume of all Windows hard disks separately

```
        foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            int bb = Convert.ToInt32(drive.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);
        }
```

And this is what returns

100GB
500GB
2300GB

But I want to collect the numbers and hand them over
But this is what I want
100GB + 500GB + 2300GB

2900GB

Comment: You must initialise a variable before the `foreach` loop, then increment the value of the variable by the desired amount.

Comment: Can you explain more fully (I am a novice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **test/run** this code on https://dotnetfiddle.net/27YcIp

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System;


Console.WriteLine(Drives.GetAllDriveSizeA());
Console.WriteLine(Drives.GetAllDriveSizeB());
Console.WriteLine(Drives.GetAllDriveSizeC());
Console.WriteLine(Drives.GetAllDriveSizeD());
Console.ReadLine();

public static class Drives
{
    public static long GetAllDriveSizeA() // With Linq
    {
        return DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(d => d.IsReady).Sum(d => d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);
    }

    public static long GetAllDriveSizeB()
    {
        long total = 0;
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()) //With foreach loop
        {
            if (drive.IsReady)
            {
                total += drive.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static long GetAllDriveSizeC()//With for loop
    {
        long total = 0;
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        for (int i = 0; i < drives.Length; i++)
        {
            if (drives[i].IsReady)
            {
                total += drives[i].TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static long GetAllDriveSizeD() //With List<T>.Foreach 
    {
        long total = 0;
        DriveInfo.GetDrives().ToList().ForEach(drive =>
        {
            if (drive.IsReady)
            {
                total += drive.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
            }
        });
        return total;
    }
}


//DriveInfo.GetDrives() - Get Drive list.
//Where(d => d.IsReady) - filters only drives(elements) that are ready otherwise will get exception when trying to get total size.
//Sum(d => d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) - Sum each element / 1024 / 1024 / 1024

//d => ....  Is lambda expression (anonymous function). d is the parameter of the function and .... is the value returned by this function.
```

**Output** my PC

```
1360
1360
1360
1360
```

**References**
[Lambda expressions](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)
[Linq - Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0)
[Linq - Sum](https://Check%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-6.0)
[List.Foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Can not do without linq?

Comment: Check new update

Answer (score 0):

This way you get the byte capacity of all your disks:

```
    int byteTotalCapacity = 0;
    foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        byteTotalCapacity += drive.TotalSize;
    }
```

if you want it in GB you must divide by (1024*1024)

Comment: This code did not work for me

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.totalsize?view=net-6.0